# RESTful interface to PHP forum software

Tags: php, api, rest, forum

I'm looking to integrate a light-weight forum feature into an existing GWT website.  The front-end is written in GWT/SmartGWT and the backend is written in PHP.  The communication is through a RESTful API using JSON.

I have looked into the forums of some popular software (SMF, phpBB, etc.) but was unable to find any references to a RESTful web API to make integration into an existing non-PHP site easier.  The closest I came is to vBulletin's Mobile API - https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/334-mobile-api.  Unfortunately, vBulletin isn't free.

Some recent threads I have seen on some of the forums basically say that the user should write their own web services wrapper around the internal API.  However, that seem like a bad solution that can lead to all kinds of additional bugs.

So, my question is this - does anyone know of an existing, free forum software (PHP, Perl, Ruby OK, but NOT Java) that provides a RESTful web services interface?

An ancillary question to this is: has anyone used Restler (http://luracast.com/products/restler/) to turn a forum software's published API into a RESTful interface?  I'm sure this method would be fraught with potential problems, but one can always hope.

PS: I saw the following older questions on stackoverflow, but they don't seem to be that helpful and are now kind of old:

- [Open-Source Forum with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069246/open-source-forum-with-api)
- [PHP forum software that integrates easily with existing website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549232/php-forum-software-that-integrates-easily-with-existing-website) -- the OP's website is built in PHP, which makes integration a lot easier
- [forum software with a simple RESTful API support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329246/forum-software-with-a-simple-restful-api-support) -- Elgg, while a great social networking framework, doesn't include a forum plugin!
- [A forum solution with an Q&A option and API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845933/a-forum-solution-with-an-qa-option-and-api) -- same issue as OP, Drupal is really heavy-weight and all I want is the forum functionality.

Comment: Did you try **elgg** [forum plugin](http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/project/595616/developer/openid_20296/forum)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [**Vanilla Forums**](http://vanillaforums.org) fits your bill, they support [JSON/XML based API](http://vanillaforums.org/page/api)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a semi-RESTful API for SMF forums that will do anything you like except create and destroy the SMF cookie (login/logout), which you might be able to accomplish yourself using cURL
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=458832.0
I think it might have been you who posted there asking for it and gave me the idea