# Logging in to a PHP site with-in an android application

Tags: android

How do I create a login on android for a PHP website I DO NOT OWN?

For example, if I want to create an app. for android that can log into a forum and you can post thing/read messages/etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the site have an API? Are you allowed to access someone else's website in such a manner (check the terms and conditions). Here are a few links to help explain APIs and some examples from popular open source projects:

- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/api-good-technology-explained/
- http://drupal.org/project/services (this is the module for Drupal that offers both a SOAP and RESTful API)
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-restful/ (Wordpress RESTFul API plugin)

A very very bad way of doing this is via spoofing the login, which I am not going to explain as it is that much of bad idea. Hypothetically you could try to spoof each of the commands to insert posts etc. IT is worth noting that many forum systems try to add protection against this.

Comment: Yes, I have spoken with site administrators and they have given me permission to create this. Also, thank you for the links!

Comment: You never said if it runs off any Open Source software (Wordpress, Drupal, PHPBB...etc). If it is custom built then an API may have to be built. Simpler option is to build a mobile site and embed it into a WebView within the app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864435/restful-interface-to-php-forum-software after a quick Google I could not see anything that provides API access to PHPBB. I would go the WebView route and make a mobile theme that works nicely on mobile devices like http://m.facebook.com/

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this using POST and GET methods?

Comment: "Hypothetically you could try to spoof each of the commands to insert posts etc.." - that is what I was getting at. I have not used PHPBB for quite some time so my knowledge is at its end sorry.